# Magento2 get the product URL in invoice mail

Tags: magento2

I want to make the items clickable in the transactional mails. I modified the order mail (items/default.phtml) and added the following code:

```
<?php $_item = $block->getItem() ?>
<a href="<?= $_item->getProductUrl(); ?>"> <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
```

However when I add the same code to the invoice mail (items/default.phtml) the value of getProductUrl() is empty.

How can I access the product URL in the invoice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try with this $_item->getProduct()->getProductUrl();

Comment: That does unfortunately not work. It'll return some admin path. Any more options?

Comment: Here you could find the solution
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132548/magento-2-get-frontend-store-url-for-a-path-in-admin

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
$product_url= $_item->getOrderItem()->getProduct()->getProductUrl();
<p class="product-name"><a href="<?= /* @noEscape */ $product_url; ?>"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
```